# Using `ant install` on Tomcat virtual host

Tags: tomcat, ant, installation, manager-app

I want to use `ant install` to deploy (and re-deploy and re-deploy) my webapp on a local virtualhost.

It works fine with the default host, but the virtual host does not have the `manager` webapp. I would like to use similar setup in the live enviromnet (no manager on the given host).

I found a promisiong property:

```
webapp.virtual.host=...
```

in some example *build.properties*, but it does not seem to get the job done. Is it even possible, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392630/advantages-of-using-tomcat-manager-app-over-copy-to-webapp-directory/5397505#5397505) to one SO post, Christian Semrau commented:

> In standard configuration, Tomcat
>   monitors its webapps folder and
>   deploys any webapp for which you copy
>   a .war file into the webapps folder,
>   and undeploys it if you remove the
>   .war file, and re-deploys it when you
>   change the .war file. But when doing
>   that, you don't get automatic feedback
>   about the success of a deployment,
>   which you do get from the Tomcat
>   Manager.

That said, your task becomes as easy as [copying or removing the file on the remote server](http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/AntTDG_chap8/index1.html).

Yet, I still don't understand why having manager app is a problem. You could, for example, only deploy it on different host/port:

```
<Connector port="8080" address="main.ip.add.ress">
  ...
  <Context path="/your_main_context">
  ...
  </Context>
</Connector>

<Connector port="18080" address="another.ip.add.ress">
  ...
  <Context path="/manager">
  ...
  </Context>
</Connector>
```

and put relevant firewall restrictions. Or, alternatively, you could place

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve"
     allow=".*\.mycompany\.com|www\.yourcompany\.com"/>
```

inside `Context` and achieve similar results.

Comment: "You could, for example, only deploy it on a certain IP/port" What do you mean by that? I want the manager app to be separated from the publicly accessible realm. That's why I currently use separate virtual hosts (but the root problem is that Manager App won't deploy cross-host).

Comment: Thanks for the example. I will award you the bounty after the lock time. Can you point me toards the docs describing this structure? (What attributes `Connector` and `Context` recognizes).

Comment: Thanks - have a look at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html and http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html (possibly, other items/links on the left menu)